# What are the permissions required in desire2learn (D2L) Valence PUT call for .../courses?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I continue to get a "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" response from a PUT request to /d2l/api/lp/1.2/courses/7917 .  This may be a permission problem with the user/role that I'm using, but I can't figure out what specific permissions may be required.  Can anyone point me to a list or matrix of valence routes and required permissions?  Or, answer for this specific one?

The same appid/userid/username works for the GETs associated with the same path.

confused...

cwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions associated with API calls should mirror the permissions you'd have to have if you were to perform the relevant function through the Learning Envrionment's web UI. You can think about this problem in two ways:

- Frame the question in terms of a user role: identify the class of users you'd reserve this ability for in your existing configuration, and ensure that a user of that role can make the call through the API as you'd expect.
- Frame the question in terms of an abstract single user: start with a role that has no privileges and add permissions until you arrive at only the ones required for the API call. This is not a trivial exercise, and the first way is far more useful in the long run.

In this particular case, because the API requires you provide a *complete* course offering set of properties when you want to update it, you have to have permission to alter all the properties in the set (under the `Manage Courses` tool). You also need to be able to *see the course info* in the first place, so you need to have `Course Management Console > See Course Info` as well.

You're probably safest to look at the permissions array in the `Manage Courses` and `Course Management Console` tools for the user roles that would do this thing in the web UI and make sure that the users employing your app also have a similar permissions array specified in those tools.

Comment: Thanks for this, in the end it turned out my problem was in my (java) code where I was attempting to PUT using HTTP POST, not sure why that resulted in an authorization problem - I suspect because the token wasn't where it should be.

I also did find two specific permissions for Offerings (my target) to update.

Comment: Please note that the authentication tokens for the user signature and the app signature in API requests is based on using (in part) the HTTP Method in the base-string to sign. So, if you call a route that should be a POST route and you do it with a PUT, this can very likely get sent back as a 403 for invalid tokens depending on how you sign the route and how you dispatch it to the service.