# Valence will give 403 on a GET lp/courses to some student users

Tags: authentication, permissions, http-status-code-403, valence

For some reason, some users who try to connect through my app receive a 403 response for the /courses end point of the valence API. See below for details:

The scenario:

- User can authenticate with Desire2Learn and is permitted to hit the
  /whoami end point. This is always the case as the API does not allow
  for this end point to require permissions.
- All routes are being retrieved by a GET request
- Other routes I receive success responses include:

  - lp/news
  - lp/enrollments/myenrollments
  - le/dropbox/folders/
- Once we try to hit lp/courses I receive a 403 forbidden.
- I see this route is deprecated in 10.3.0, The D2L instance I am working with is on version 10.1.0

I'm wondering if this is a group permissions issue or if my authentication is incorrect (it does work for multiple other requests)? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Related to this question, which asks what permissions are necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742762/what-are-the-permissions-required-in-desire2learn-d2l-valence-put-call-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the /courses endpoint did not have the right authentication for my user. IT turns out though that this was for good reason. Luckily I could use the information gathered in /myenrollments instead.